# SML : how to compare (< or >) two equality types

Tags: sml

I am having an issue with the following code, in SML :

```
fun inter s1 s2 =
  let
    fun inter' [] _ interSet = interSet
      | inter' _ [] interSet = interSet 
      | inter' (x1::s1) (x2::s2) interSet =
            if x1=x2 then
                inter' s1 s2 (x1::interSet) (* Add the value to the intersection and advance in both s1 and s2*)
            else if x1 < x2 then
                inter' s1 (x2::s2) interSet (* Keep going through s1 *)
            else
                inter' (x1::s1) s2 interSet (* Keep going through s2 *)
   in
      if s1=[] orelse s2=[] then []
      else                          
        inter' s1 s2 []
end;
```

The *inter* function returns a list containing the intersection between two ORDERED lists s1 and s2 (i.e. values found in both s1 and s2). I was expecting it to work for all equality types, but the function type is :

```
val inter = fn: int list -> int list -> int list
```

Why is it not :

```
val inter = fn: ''a list -> ''a list -> ''a list    ?
```

It looks like the problem comes from

```
x1 < x2
```

Was I wrong in believing that the < operator was overloaded for all equality types ? Shouldn't it be able to compare strings for example ?

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark answers as accepted if they help you. Also, upvote them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you were wrong to believe that. If equality types supported ordering they'd probably be called ordered types. ;)

What you need to do is pass in your comparison operator as an argument to the `inter` function. Alternatively, if this is part of a larger module, you could consider making that a functor. In both cases I would suggest passing not a less-then operator, but a 3-way function `compare : 'a * 'a -> order`, as is predefined for each of the builtin types, e.g., `Int.compare`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! This all makes sense now :).